# Reading a subvalue from an XML tag

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm reading a XML file and parsing it using Obj-C and cocoa. I am reading the values using the following line (to read the `<DocOwner>` tag):

```
NSArray* DocownerArray = [root nodesForXPath:@"//DocOwner" error:nil];
        for(NSXMLElement* xmlElement in DocownerArray)
            [DocOwner addObject:[xmlElement stringValue]];
```

but I ran into a problem, in cases where I have the following:

```
<Discover id="1234">SomeValue</Discover>
```

using the previous method will return `SomeValue` but no the `id=1234`. How can I parse that part?

This is done on XCode 4 for Mac OS X.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried NSXMLElement's attributeForName method like

```
[DocOwner addObject:[[xmlElement attributeForName:@"id"] stringValue]];
```

and get the stringValue from the returning NSXMLNode?

Comment: Thanks, how do I call that with the code sample I posted in the question?

Comment: Hmmm... I think either I did it wrong or I am missing something, getting `[xmlElement attributeForName:@"id"]` I get `id="1234"` and not `1234`

Comment: What you get when you try this? [[xmlElement attributeForName:@"id"] stringValue]